# AngularJS term length check

Tags: angularjs

I will fetch User from the backend and therefore I will give in a name into an input field and then the Controller Method getUserByTerm will be invoked. 
This works fine.
My question now would be, if the implementation is ok or is there an additional support of Angular that makes it easier? Currently the if(term.length > 3) looks very "Javascript- like".
Thanks for help!

```
angular
    .module('project.management')
    .controller('ManagementController', ManagementController);

function ManagementController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.getUsersByTerm = getUsersByTerm;

    function getUsersByTerm(term) {
        if(term.length > 3) {
            alert('get User By term: ' + term);
        }
    }
};


<div ng-controller="ManagementController as vm">
<form class="well form-search">
    <label>Usersuche:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-change="vm.getUsersByTerm(term)" ng-model="term" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Username">
    <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="vm.getUsersByTerm(term)">Suchen</button>
</form>
<pre ng-model="result">
    {{result}}
</pre>
   </div>
```

Comment: very "Javascript- like", is a good thing right? You're writing JavaScript after all.. If you want to make something more 'Angular-y' then you can look into writing a directive that handles validation, or read about it https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ng-maxlength="3"` to your input and submit only if form is valid (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)

Although, your code is quite simple and this might not be required.

```
<form class="well form-search" ng-submit-"vm.getUsersByTerm(term)">
    <label>Usersuche:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-change="vm.getUsersByTerm(term)"
     ng-model="term" ng-maxlength="3" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Username">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Suchen</button>
</form>
```